# Why does inserting navigation create unrecognized selector sent?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

On my app I decided to change my segue to a Show Details segue in the story board as I wanted the affect of the storyboard coming from the bottom of the screen, and thus I needed some way to bring the user back, so I inserted a navigation into the destination view. However now I get:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setImageData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbdfa887600'**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"infoSegue"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        DetailsViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        int num = (int)[self getIndexNum];

        NSString *dictionaryKey = _results[num];
        Image *image = _dataDictionary[dictionaryKey];
        vc.imageData = image;
        NSLog(@"Vendor ID %@",image.vendorId);

    }
}
```

Has the navigation become the parent of the view or something?

Comment: what is DetailsVIewCOntroller ? a uiviewcontroller or navigation controller ?

Comment: imageData  is kind of NSData or image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your destination view controller is a navigation controller, then you shouldn't set the image on navigation controller!! Also as @vadian from the answer said, you need to cast the return type of `uiviewcontroller`!!!

```
UINavigationController *navController = [segue destinationViewController];
DetailsViewController *viewController = (DetailsViewController *)([navController viewControllers][0]);
[viewController setimageData:image];
```

Make sure imageData is of kind `UIImage`. If it is of type `NSData`, you might need to do:

```
 [viewController setimageData:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
```

Answer (score 2):

As `destinationViewController` returns the generic type `UIViewController` you have to do a type cast.

```
DetailsViewController *vc = (DetailsViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
```